# Загрузка формы из другой сборки

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Создал библиотеку классов в которой хранятся множество форм. Теперь пытаюсь из другой сборки загрузить одну из форм.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("ClassLibrary.dll");
Type t = asm.GetType("ClassLibrary.Form1");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Show()");
method.Invoke(obj, null);
```

И в последней строке возникает exception

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Что в полне логично =) Вопрос в том как создать экземпляр класса?

Comment: `t.GetMethod("Show()")` => `t.GetMethod("Show")`

Comment: Тогда возникает исключение
"Обнаружено неоднозначное соответствие."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основная ошибка: опечатка, в данную функцию передается имя метода, а не пример вызова.

Таким образом вместо `"Show()"` нужно `"Show"`

Класс формы наследуется от класса `Control`, и, соответственно, наследует его метод `Show` без аргументов, но кроме этого у него есть свой собственный метод `Show`, который принимает владельца формы.

Чтобы уточнить какой именно из методов нужно выбрать, можно использовать перегрузку метода [`GetMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx) где вторым параметром передается массив типов аргументов.

Так как нужный метод не имеет параметров. нужно передать пустой массив.

```
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Show",new Type[0]);
```